# How do I get the status of a child process from a parent, i.e. has it stopped, continued, or exited? For Linux, C lang

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, child-process

This is a C language program in Linux (ubuntu). I've been trying to figure out how to get the status of a child process from a parent.

I've written a simple child process that counts to 25 over 25 seconds and outputs a tick count to standard output.   In the parent process I *1> stop the child process* for a couple of seconds.  *2> continue* it for a couple of seconds and then *3> kill the child process.*    I want to get the status of the child process, for which I've been using the **waitpid()** function.  However, I find that if I used the flags:

**waitCondition = WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED**

it does return the "stopped" status, but it hangs when it's in the continue state.

Conversely, if I set the flags to:

**waitCondition= WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED | WNOHANG**

The stop status is not registered, but the continue status is registered by waitpid().

**I'm trying to get the parent to recognize the state when it has stopped, continued or exited.**

I have the code below. Does anyone have any ideas for this?  Thanks!

```
int waiting4pid()(pid_t processID)
{   
    int waitCondition = WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED;
    int currentState;

    while (waitpid(processID,&currentState,waitCondition) > 0){

        if(WIFCONTINUED(currentState)){
            printf("\n currentState = continued!\n");
        }
        if(WIFSIGNALED(currentState)){
            printf("\n currentState = signaled!\n");            
        }
        if(WIFSTOPPED(currentState)){
            printf("\n currentState = stopped!\n");
        }
        
    }
}

void sigTest()
{ 
    pid_t processID;

    processID = fork();
    if(processID ==0) { // child
       // tmp/loop is an application that counts to 25 in 25 seconds and then exits.
       execlp("tmp/loop", "tmp/loop", NULL);
    }else{ 
        sleep(2);
        printf("\n Stop!");
        kill(processID, SIGSTOP);
        waiting4pid()(processID);
        
        sleep(2);
        printf("\n Continue!");      
        kill(processID,SIGCONT);
        waiting4pid()(processID);
        
        sleep(2);
        printf("\n Kill!"); 
        kill(processID, SIGKILL);
        waiting4pid()(processID);
    }
}

void main() 
{    
    sigTest();
}
```

Comment: How do you expect the `waitpidstatus` function to exit the `while` loop? You send a signal to the child then call `waitpidstatus`. The `waitpidstatus` will then pick up a change in state and go back to waiting for the next state change. But there will be no next state change as the parent is now blocked on `waitpidstatus` so it cannot send the next signal.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks!  I had a misconception about how waitpid() works.

Answer (score 2):

In order to check if the process exited, do:

```
if(WIFEXITED(status) {

    // do your stuff

    // you can also check the exit status
    if(WEXITSTATUS(status) != EXIT_SUCCESS) {
        // the child process exited with error
    }
}
```

As already mentioned by @kaylum in a comment under the question, the `waitpid()` call blocks until the child changes state. But you can modify this behaviour by calling `waitpid()` with `WNOHANG` flag set (that would be useful if you need to monitor the child process but at the same time do some other stuff in the parent; alternatively you can `waitpid()` in a separate thread).